# How to change the color of shadow's Frame in Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to change the shadow color of the Xamarin Forms Frame element?

Answer (score 4):

You can either achieve it with custom renderers, or use [RedCorner Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RedCorners.Forms)

They have a custom frame (Frame2) with several options, including Frame Shadow Color

Here is a sample image :

[image]

Usage:

```
<rf:Frame2 
    HasShadow="True" 
    ShadowRadius="20" 
    ShadowColor="Red"
    BackgroundColor="White">
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill" HeightRequest="100">
        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Hello, World" />
    </Grid>
</rf:Frame2>
```

You can read more in the [official documentation.](https://redcorners.com/forms/frame2/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I installed the NuGet package and followed the procedure but unfortunately I can't change the color of the shadow (in reality it doesn't create any shadow around the Frame2 element). I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, this is my piece of code:

Comment: `code`
<rf:Frame2 HasShadow="True" ShadowRadius="10" CornerRadius="30" ShadowColor="Orange" BackgroundColor="Green" Padding="30" Margin="60">
                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill" HeightRequest="100">
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Hello, World" />
                    </Grid>
                </rf:Frame2>

Comment: The property "ShadowColor" work well only iOS, but not wok in Android

Comment: Try and open an issue of the Nuget Github Page